# React Native - LayoutAnimation: how to make it just animate object inside component, not whole component/view?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, layout-animation

I'm trying to follow this **[example](https://medium.com/@Jpoliachik/react-native-s-layoutanimation-is-awesome-4a4d317afd3e)** (code **[here](https://gist.github.com/Jpoliachik/0dd83689646d1051b0bc)**) and employ **LayoutAnimation** inside my RN project (the difference from that example being that I just want to render my circles with no button that'll be pressed).

But when I've added LayoutAnimation, it's **the whole view/screen/component that does the animation of 'springing in', not just the circles as I desire**. Where do I have to move LayoutAnimation to in order to achieve just the circle objects being animated?

**UPDATED AGAIN**: Heeded `bennygenel`'s advice to make a separate Circles component and then on Favorites, have a `componentDidMount` that would add each Cricle component one by one, resulting in individual animation as the state gets updated with a time delay. But I'm still not getting the desired effect of the circles rendering/animating one by one...

```
class Circle extends Component {
  componentWillMount() {
    LayoutAnimation.configureNext(LayoutAnimation.Presets.spring);
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <View>
          { this.props.children }
        </View>
    );
  }
}

class Favorites extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      circleCount: 0
    }
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    for(let i = 0; i <= this.props.screenProps.appstate.length; i++) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.addCircle();
      }, (i*500));
    }
  }
  addCircle = () => {
    this.setState((prevState) => ({circleCount: prevState.circleCount + 1}));
  }

render() {
    var favoritesList = this.props.screenProps.appstate;

    circles = favoritesList.map((item) => {
        return (
            <Circle key={item.url} style={styles.testcontainer}>
              <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {
                  Alert.alert( "Add to cart and checkout?",
                              item.item_name + "? Yum!",
                              [
                                {text: 'Yes', onPress: () => console.log(item.cust_id)},
                                {text: 'Cancel', onPress: () => console.log('Cancel Pressed'), style: 'cancel'}
                              ]
                              )}}>
                <Image source={{uri: item.url}} />
               </TouchableOpacity>
            </Circle>
        )});

    return (
        <ScrollView}>
          <View>
            <View>
              {circles}
            </View>
          </View>
        </ScrollView>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [`configureNext()`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/layoutanimation.html#configurenext) docs;

> `static configureNext(config, onAnimationDidEnd?)`
>
> Schedules an animation to happen on the next layout.

This means you need to configure `LayoutAnimation` just before the render of the component you want to animate. If you separate your `Circle` component and set the `LayoutAnimation` for that component you can animate the circles and nothing else in your layout.

**Example**

```
class Circle extends Component {
  componentWillMount() {
    LayoutAnimation.configureNext(LayoutAnimation.Presets.spring);
  }

  render() {
    return (<View style={{width: 50, height: 50, backgroundColor: 'red', margin: 10, borderRadius: 25}}/>);
  }
}

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      circleCount: 0
    }
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    for(let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.addCircle();
      }, (i*200));
    }
  }
  addCircle = () => {
    this.setState((prevState) => ({circleCount: prevState.circleCount + 1}));    
  }
  render() {
    var circles = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < this.state.circleCount; i++) {
      circles.push(<Circle />);
    }
    return (
    <View>
      <View style={{flexDirection:'row', justifyContent:'center', alignItems: 'center', marginTop: 100}}>
        { circles }
      </View>
      <Button color="blue" title="Add Circle" onPress={this.addCircle} />
    </View>
    );
  }
}
```

**Update**

If you want to use `Circle` component as your example you need to use it like below so the child components can be rendered too. More detailed explanation can be found [here](https://mxstbr.blog/2017/02/react-children-deepdive/).

```
class Circle extends Component {
  componentWillMount() {
    LayoutAnimation.configureNext(LayoutAnimation.Presets.spring);
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <View>
          { this.props.children }
        </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: hey @bennygenel -- thanks for your response. I've been trying your suggestion albeit in a slightly different implementation -- I'm struggling to get it to work though. I've added it onto the UPDATE section under my original question, perhaps there's a quick thing you see that I am doing incorrectly in trying to implement your suggestion? thanks!

Comment: thanks Benny, i knew I forgot something basic as passing down those props. The circles do render now as they are supposed to, but the LayoutAnimation still spring the whole view instead of each circle --- basically the whole view/page 'swoops' in, instead of the circles individually doing so. any idea?

Comment: @SpicyClubSauce I was trying to explain that. LayoutAnimation animate the next render. Since your circles render at the same time they all animate. That is why I gave a delay to the circles in my example and render them one by one. You need to implement similar logic to yours.

Comment: Makes sense @bennygenel -- I made one more (hopefully last) update to the question taking your suggestion. Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong there?

Comment: @SpicyClubSauce the error is pretty clear. You are trying to set state after your component unmounted because you have a timeout set. you gave a 2 seconds delay and if you have 10 items the 10th item will be added after 20 seconds.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166205/discussion-between-spicyclubsauce-and-bennygenel).

Comment: This doesn't work well with react navigation or any other animations - LayoutAnimation still affects all animations globally

Comment: I'm having the same issue, the answer has been accepted by @SpicyClubSauce were you able to achieve the desired animation?